# How to set tics in x or y axis using range in GNU Octave?

Tags: octave, yaxis

length of x = 1000,
length of y = 1000

```
plot(x, y, '+');
xlabel ("p");
ylabel ("Q(p)");
title('Custom plot');
set(gca, 'xtick', [0.00000   0.20000   0.40000   0.60000   0.80000   1.00000])
```

This *set* command creates 6 tics in X axis, but I like to create 20 ticks so that there are 50 elements in between 2 tics.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain further what your problem is. If you want to create 20 ticks then create a vector with 20 elements.

Comment: Without creating static vector, is there any way to set fixed difference between tics dynamically? For example, from 1 to 1000 if we want every 20 with equal distance, the tics will be at 0, 20, 40, 60, and so on. Is there any way

Comment: Yes, sure. Just use a range 0:20:1000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment I guess you don't know the concept behind Octaves "range". [see here](https://octave.org/doc/interpreter/Ranges.html#Ranges)

In your case if you want the xticks go from 0 to 1000 and the difference between the steps is 20 just use:

```
set(gca, 'xtick', 0:20:1000);
```

Comment: or `xticks(0:20:1000);`