# Can’t set ticks in octave

Tags: octave

It has been over a decade since I last used octave. I thought I still remembered some things. I confidently typed:

```
x = [1961,1962,1963, 1964, 1965,...
   1966, 1967, 1968, 1969, 1970,...
   1971, 1972, 1973, 1974, 1975,...
   1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980,...
   1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985,...
   1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990,...
    1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995,...
   1996, 1997, 1998, ...
    1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, ...
    2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, ...
    2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, ...
    2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018];
y = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0,...
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...
   0, 1, 0, 2, 0,...
   1, 0, 1, 0, 1,...
    2, 1, 0, 0, 0,...
   0, 2, 2, ...
    14, 21 ,23, 7, 7,...
    1, 3, 5, 4, 3, ...
    5, 5, 3, 7, 4, ...
    7, 3, 3, 4, 4];


plot(x,y)
set(gca, 'xtick', 1960:5:2020);
```

But I just don’t get the tick spacing - one tick every 5 units - I desire. This is what comes out: 
[image]

It must be some beginner‘s mistake. So I checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52675459/how-to-set-tics-in-x-or-y-axis-using-range-in-gnu-octave) and on numerous other pages, but I just don’t see it!

I am using the app Anoc for iPad, though I greatly doubt it is the app’s fault. ;)

Comment: I think you’re doing it right. Must be the app’s fault.

Comment: What graphics_toolkit is this? Is this "Anoc" a GPLv2 violation?

Comment: @Andy I don’t know. This is the app’s info on the iStore (what i get if I choose “share”): Anoc Pro Octave Editor by Verbosus.com I shall try to find out more,

Comment: I get the intended result on my standard Octave installation. One thing I can think of is that it may be problematic relying on 'what's open' when delegating to a middleman app. Try capturing the plot into a handle and use that handle directly in the 'set' function, and see if that works for you (e.g. `h = plot(x,y);   set(get(h, 'parent'), 'xtick', 1960:5:2020);`).

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou parse error near line 39 of file /verbosus/octave/work/419042e3-a5b3-4377-9dcc-1014bf0a208a/test.m    syntax error  >>> h = plot(x,y); set(get(h, 'parent'),'xtick', 1960:5:2020;))                                                             ^  error: source: error sourcing file '/verbosus/octave/work/419042e3-a5b3-4377-9dcc-1014bf0a208a/test.m' Haven’t understood the syllogism yet. Perhaps you implied something obvious, that I didn’t do?

Comment: @Ludi your errors sound increasingly likely to be a problem with Verbosus rather than with your syntax. Feel free to submit a bug with them. In the meantime, I would recommend http://octave-online.net as an alternative browser interface that is usable from a phone. Logging in allows you to upload scripts too, as well as sharing and lots of other tricks.

Comment: You do have a syntax error here: `h = plot(x,y); set(get(h, 'parent'),'xtick', 1960:5:2020;))`. That should be: `h = plot(x,y); set(get(h, 'parent'),'xtick', 1960:5:2020);` -- Note the different placing of the `;` and the parentheses at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I'm the developer of the Anoc app)

Anoc itself is only an editor (as the name Anoc Octave Editor says). Please keep in mind that there is no plot generation on the device.

As for your question: Please write a draw_plot command after the set() function and wrap the plot calls inside a hold on and hold off. This will fix the tick-issue.

```
x = [1961,1962,1963, 1964, 1965,...
   1966, 1967, 1968, 1969, 1970,...
   1971, 1972, 1973, 1974, 1975,...
   1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980,...
   1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985,...
   1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990,...
    1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995,...
   1996, 1997, 1998, ...
    1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, ...
    2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, ...
    2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, ...
    2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018];
y = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0,...
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...
   0, 1, 0, 2, 0,...
   1, 0, 1, 0, 1,...
    2, 1, 0, 0, 0,...
   0, 2, 2, ...
    14, 21 ,23, 7, 7,...
    1, 3, 5, 4, 3, ...
    5, 5, 3, 7, 4, ...
    7, 3, 3, 4, 4];

hold on
plot(x,y)
set(gca, 'xtick', 1960:5:2020);
draw_plot
hold off
```